# wpf drop shadow on submenu

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu

This is a sample xaml -

How can I make the submenu of the context menu look the same as the main parent context menu (including drop shadow) ?

Thanks.

```
<Window x:Class="dummy.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dummy"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Click for ContextMenu" Width="166" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="Test" HasDropShadow="True">
                    <MenuItem Header="File"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="View"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Recent Files">
                        <MenuItem Header="file1.txt"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="file2.txt"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: They looks the same for me, have both the shadow.

Comment: strange - not here, created a new project in blend (2017) just with the above xaml and the submenu has no dropshadow and vertical line between the icon and header is different too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the default behaviour (or look) on Windows 10.

[image]

If you add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` (Project->Add Reference->Assemblies->Framework in Visual Studio) you could apply the Aero Windows 7 styles to the `ContextMenu` like this:

```
<Button Content="Click for ContextMenu" Width="166" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="Test" HasDropShadow="True">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="File"/>
            <MenuItem Header="View"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Recent Files">
                <MenuItem Header="file1.txt"/>
                <MenuItem Header="file2.txt"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: do you know where this is documented?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on VS 2015, Windows 7, both have shadow:

[image]